# How to handle filename encodings correctly?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I need to get the filename out of an File-Object. However every method I use ends up in a different result when it comes to special cases like these:

Example 1: Bildschirmfoto 2017-03-14 um 21.28.42.png

Example 2: Jagdfasan+1+m%C3%A4nnl..jpg

There are different object properties to get a filename of an object. See https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html

i.e. when I try **file.fsName** I get

Example 1: Bildschirmfoto 2017-03-14 um 21.28.42.png (correct)

Example 2: Jagdfasan+1+männl..jpg (wrong)

but when I use **file.name** I get

Example 1: Bildschirmfoto%202017-03-14%20um%2021.28.42.png (wrong)

Example 2: Jagdfasan+1+m%C3%A4nnl..jpg (correct)

Here is a simple script that outputs the paths of a selected file using **File.decode(file.name)**

```
function rei_Testfunction() {
// Testfunction

    var file = File.openDialog("Choose File...");
    if(file === null){

    }else{
     alert("File.decode(file.name): " + File.decode(file.name) + "\n");
    }
}

rei_Testfunction();
```

I expect to get the real filename for further operations and not some decoded/encoded variations of it.

Comment: Use [`File.decode(file.name)`](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html#decode). Given your current function, you should change the line that currently reads: `+"name: " + file.name + "\n"` in your alert to `+"name: " + File.decode(file.name) + "\n"`.

Comment: @RobC
thank you for your help. However this method still changes
`Jagdfasan+1+m%C3%A4nnl..jpg` to `Jagdfasan+1+männl..jpg`.

Comment: @RobC
There seems to be an issue with OS/X. Your way works well on Windows. However on Mac this method behaves differently.

Comment: Interesting, I get the correct desired results on both mac OSX and Windows.. Is your mac OSX set to use a particular language? Mine is set to English.

Comment: Well yes. Mine is set to German. Strange if this made the difference.

Comment: Seems to make no difference for me. When I set the mac OSX language to Deutsch I continue to get the same desired result. Perhaps [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57137098/edit) to include the revised `Testfunction`  that you are now trying.

Comment: Thank you RobC, helping me with this. I edited the function.
Now something interesting happened. I wanted to copy&paste the alert which gave me "Jagdfasan+1+männl..jpg"  into this comment. Surprisingly the result was "Jagdfasan+1+m%C3%A4nnl..jpg". What do we learn about this?
It is not what I see what I get? I will try it in my real script to be sure.

Comment: My assumption is that the `File.decode(file.name)` part is working correctly - it's just not being interpreted correctly via the UI layer (i.e. in the Alert dialog). Perhaps it's an issue/bug on your version of macOS - as I cannot reproduce it. Try testing for equality using [this test function](https://paste.ee/p/pZmNy).  If you run the script and select the file named `Jagdfasan+1+m%C3%A4nnl..jpg` it should alert _"Yes - the decoded filename does match the given comparator"_ the first time, and  _"No - the decoded filename does NOT match the given comparator"_ the second time it is chosen.

Comment: I tried your function on macOS. It alerts the other way around. First No then Yes. On windows I will check the next day I get into office. It is really weird as it feels like I can't even trust in the string I can see. Therefore it is hard to tell at what point the failure happens.

Comment: That's weird. I'm interested to know what happens when you run the same function on Windows. You may want to try different [ExtendScript Localization](https://estk.aenhancers.com/8%20-%20ExtendScript%20Tools%20and%20Features/localizing-extendscript-strings.html) settings. For instance; try running [this test script](https://paste.ee/p/ykigX) to see if the correct filename is shown in the alert. Note the `$.locale = "en"` part - the `en` sets the locale to English. Try running it as-is to see what happens, then also try setting it to `de` (Deutsch), e.g. `$.locale = "de"` and run it again.

Comment: Ok, I have tested the Yes-No-function on Windows. And the result is as you expected.
Your second function works fine and shows the correct filename on Windows.

Comment: Ok, hopefully the second function also shows the correct result on macOS.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I will search for another Mac to test this function. If it works on your system maybe there is something on mine.

Comment: The only thing that I could find out is the following definition for the File-constructor:
[https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-constructor]
_Note: Underlying OS filesystems use differing conventions for file name_

I don't know if this means that it depends on the OS

Comment: The [W3C's File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-constructor]) is not the same as the [ExtendScript File Object](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html) - they're two completely different specifications.

Comment: Have you tried using `file.fsName` instead of just `file.name`?